# @ControllerAdvice only meant for Centralized/Global Exception Handling or any other things we can do with this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is this only for Centralized Exception Handling ? if not,
what are the other things we can achieve from this annotation.

Answer (score 1):

@ControllerAdvice is only used as a global @ExceptionHandler. Instead of having multiple ExceptionHandlers in your controllers you can have a single global component with this annotation.

There is no other usage for it that I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it to provide @ModelAttributes to all adviced @Controllers.